# How can I create a recursive function that returns a list without it becoming more than two dimension? (Python)

Tags: python, list, recursion, dynamic

I am following [this](https://youtu.be/oBt53YbR9Kk?t=10055) tutorial on YouTube. I am trying to create a function that takes two inputs, a target word and a bank of words, and returns a 2d array of all possible combinations from the word bank to get to the target word.

For example, `canConstruct("abc", ["ab", "c", "abc", "d"])` should return `[["ab","c"],["abc"]]`

There are quite a few flaw in my code, but the main one I am focusing on now is getting the final output to be a 2d list.

I have tried returning the list back in multiple ways. I thought returning `*list` might work as when I print out `str(*list)` is seems to remove the extra `[]` but I can't return this.

Here is the relevant code:

```py
    
    result = []

    def allConstruct(target, wordBank, memo = {}):
        if target == "":
            return([[]])
    
        if target in memo:
            return memo[target]
    
        for word in wordBank:

            ...

            # if match never gets set to False, that means word is a subset of target
            if match == True:
                #remove word from beginning of target
                new_target = target[word_len:]
                suffix_ways = allConstruct(new_target, wordBank)
                for way in suffix_ways:
                    print("inserting word: " + word + " at start of list: " + str(way))
                    way.insert(0, word) 
                    print("The result is " + str(way))
                result.append(suffix_ways)
                memo[target] = result
    
        memo[target] = result
        return result
```

I have made my test case super simple so I can better understand the error checking print statements. Below is what I pass into the function:

```py
result = allConstruct("ab", ["ab", "a"])
print(result)
```

The output is this:

```py
inserting word: ab at start of list: []
The result is ['ab']
inserting word: a at start of list: [['ab']]
The result is ['a', ['ab']]
[['a', ['ab']], [...]]
```

Apart from the glaring issue that "aab" is not the target word, my returning list is `['a',['ab']]` when it should be `[['a', 'ab']]`.

I think the issue might be at `way.insert(0, word)` but I'm really not too sure as I've confused myself quite a bit.

Any advice on how to pass a list back in a recursive function so it doesn't become a mess would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are these issues:

- `result` should not be a global variable, because you get a result from the recursive call, and you merge that back into `result`. This will lead to duplicate information. Moreover, when `result` is global, you have a function with side effects, and the caller should reset `result` whenever it wants to make a new call. This is bad practice.

  Instead let `result` be a *local* name, which is set to `[]` at the start of the function, and is returned to the caller.
- You don't want to `append` the result from the recursive call, since that result has the *same* 2D structure as the one you build. So you need to use `extend` instead.
- Not your issue, but `memo = {}` as default valued parameter is a bad idea. Instead let the default value be `None`, and assign the empty dictionary inside the body of the function. Otherwise a next call of the function will keep using the previously populated memo, which is undesired.

Here is a correction:

```
def allConstruct(target, wordBank, memo = None):
    if not memo:
        memo = {}  # Initialise for *every* toplevel call
    result = []  # Local!

    if target == "":
        return [[]]

    if target in memo:
        return memo[target]

    for word in wordBank:
        word_len = len(word)
        match = target.startswith(word)

        # if match never gets set to False, that means word is a subset of target
        if match == True:
            # Remove word from beginning of target
            new_target = target[word_len:]
            suffix_ways = allConstruct(new_target, wordBank)
            for way in suffix_ways:
                print("inserting word: " + word + " at start of list: " + str(way))
                way.insert(0, word) 
                print("The result is " + str(way))
            result.extend(suffix_ways)  # Extend!
            memo[target] = result

    memo[target] = result
    return result
```

Comment: Amazing explanations, thank you for making this clearer - and I didn't know extend existed! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
def allConstruct(target, wordBank):
new_res=[]
result = []  # Local!
memo=None
if not memo:
    memo = {}  # Initialise for *every* toplevel call

if target == "":
    return [[]]

if target in memo:
    return memo[target]

for word in wordBank:
    word_len = len(word)
    match = target.startswith(word)

    # if match never gets set to False, that means word is a subset of target
    if match == True:
        # Remove word from beginning of target
        new_target = target[word_len:]
        suffix_ways = allConstruct(new_target, wordBank)
        for way in suffix_ways:
            print("inserting word: " + word + " at start of list: " + str(way))
            way.insert(0, word)
            print("The result is " + str(way))
            new_res.append(way)
print(new_res)
return new_res
```